# Uploading app to testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

So I've been trying to upload my app to test flight following this guide:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iIr2uN5Yj8

1. I've created AppID, using Bundle Identifier from my App. I can see it in my App IDs.
2. I've created a provisioning profile for iOS Distribution. If I check in Xcode->preferences->accounts->my account I can see that new profile there.
3. I've added new iOS app in iTunes Connect. I used my AppID I've created before as my Bundle ID. As for version, I just put 1.0 there just as it says in my app (Version: 1.0 Build: 1)
4. Used some random SKU.
5. In Xcode I archived my App but there was no button to submit it to TestFlight. I could only export the .ipa file, validate it, upload to App Store or Download dSYMs (if I click that one it would say that "an app record for "appID" was found but a matching version for 1.0 build 1 was not.

So what have I done wrong here? Is it the version? Should I've put there not just 1.0 but 1.0 (1) instead?

Update:
Could the reason be that I didn't activate TestFlight Beta?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a distribution-based provisioning profile selected for *Release* in the *Build Settings*?

Comment: use the submit to app store button

Comment: added some more info

Comment: hi @ArseniiNibble you need to select  `upload to App Store` button and then it will be uploaded to iTunes for Testing. then you can release it on iTunes or allow your Internal/External users to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose `Upload to App Store` option in Archive. As all the applications are by default uploaded to `TestFlight`, then while you are submitting it for `iTunes` you need to select which build you want to publish or put in review.

Once your app is successfully uploaded it will appear in `prerelease` section. Initially it will show `Uploaded` state, then after some time it will turn to `Processing` at last you will be able to open it for your `Internal` users.

> For more details you can always refer [Apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

[image: I have added screenshot for your guideline here].

Comment: Thank you. How much time it usually takes for an app to appear in Test Flight? I've uploaded it just now and it says "Processing". I got the "the resulting api analysis file is too large" warning though.

Comment: @ArseniiNibble it usually be available `within half an hour` but depending on rush on iTunes it may vary.

Comment: Got it. The "upload to app store" button made me anxious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `upload to App Store`.
2. Go to iTunes connect -> Prerelease and select TestFlight Beta Testing

[image: iTunes connect]

Comment: You missed about 12 steps.

Comment: Thanks! How much time it usually takes for an app to appear in TestFlight so I can enable Beta Testing?

Comment: For internal testing, it should not take more than half an hour, for external testing you have to wait for apple's approval, which will take a few days.